# single char strcat -C

Tags: c, char, strcat

I want to put two single `char` together.
Should I use the function strcat?

the following is my code

```
int main(){
    char *a[4]={"1","2","3","4"};
    char *new_a[2];    
   for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    new_a[i]=strcat(a[2*i],a[2*i+1]);
    printf("%c",*new_a[i]);
   }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to print new_a[0] to be 12, and new_a[1] to be 34

Comment: *How* do you use `strcat`? *What* is supposed to be "{12,34}"? Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), as well as learn how to create a [mcve] of your attempt to show us inside the question itself.

Comment: What you want is not clear. You have 4 pointers on characters (not 4 characters) and you want... two strings?

Comment: You mean like `char a[4][3]={"1","2","3","4"}; strcat (a[0], a[1]); strcat (a[2], a[3]); printf ("{%s,%s}\n", a[0], a[2]);` ??

Comment: sorry it's my first time to ask question here .
I just want   4 pointers on characters  to be two  2 pointers on characters 
like converting   char *a[4]={"1","2","3","4"};  to be  char *b[2]={"12","34"};

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Thank you ! 
I already edited what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Without being 100% sure what you need, here is some code that gives the output you suggest, by concatenating the first and the last two characters of your character array together.

Also note that what you have is *not* an array of characters, by an array of pointer, so you might want to have a look into it as well.

**Here is the code:**

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void){
    char a[4]={'1','2','3','4'};
    char str[8] = {'{', a[0], a[1], ',', a[2], a[3], '}', '\0'};
    printf("string: %s\n",str);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
string: {12,34}
```

Comment: I don't think OP literally meant to include the `{}` and the `,`s in the output.